# Creating an mini electronic ignititer that can ignite lighter fluid possible?

Tags: batteries, dc, switch-mode-power-supply, safety

Hello i'm new to electronics but I have a project where I want to create a mini electronic igniting device that will be able to light wicks that are soaked in naphtha (lighter fluid) safely, reliably and almost instantly (like a flint would).

I need the device to be activated with a slide switch, and be small enough to fit in a 4" wide x 2.5" high x 1/8"~1/4" thick.

I would prefer the battery to last as long as possible, in other words not just several uses. Would button cell batteries be sufficient for this space/power-wise?

I mostly want to know if creating something like this is possible/feasible myself, or if the space is not sufficient enough to light something like lighter fluid electronically.

Essentially I want to create my own version of something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UlXeJKQOGE
Its a fire wallet that also seems to be able to light business cards on fire as you take them out leaving them unharmed, it seems lighter fluid at some point is used on the business cards as well, and possibly a secondary device for lighting them. Unfortunately they're not for sale anywhere anymore though.

I've wanted to create my own wallet for a while, and own a flint fire wallet, but wanted to see if i could incorporate a fire feature in my wallet electronically.

Comment: I think there are two choices. A spark (may not be energetic enough to light naptha) or a hot wire. The hot wire will do it for sure, but may be a bit slower. For a hot wire you would be looking at nichrome wire or something similar.

Comment: This looks cool.   -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEsWdrQ-qQ0

Comment: What's wrong with the spark generator in a cigarette lighter? Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create an electric arc that can ignite the lighter fluid.

Generally you need about 3000 / mm for electricity to jump a spark gap.  So if you had a 1mm gap, you would need 3000V, a 1/3mm gap 1000V, etc.  So the problem boils down to creating a compact high voltage generator.